# JPanel not keeping color alpha when changing background

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel

Ever so slowly the jpanel's background color will become more opaque than it previously was. Notable I am using the setBackground method of the jpanel. Here are a few links to code you might want to look at.

[Custom GUI Button](https://bitbucket.org/deadrecon98/family-comm/src/fe50c30a14a69adfb5b34bebedda2a490cc69a7d/src/FamilyComm/Client/GUI/Component/GuiButton.java?at=master)

[The Gui it's in](https://bitbucket.org/deadrecon98/family-comm/src/fe50c30a14a69adfb5b34bebedda2a490cc69a7d/src/FamilyComm/Client/GUI/GuiSettings.java?at=master)  -- Look at line 158.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things popout

1. Swing doesn't support alpha based colors, either a Swing component is opaque or transparent. You have to fake it, by making the component transparent and then override `paintComponent` and use a `AlphaCompositeto` fill it, otherwise Swing won't know it should be painting under you component and you'll end up wi a bunch more paint issues
2. In your `TranslucentPanel`, you're allowing the component to paint its background and then fill it again with a translucent versions of it, doubling up. You need to set this component to transparent

The first thing I would do is change the `TranslucentPane` so you can control the transparency level, for example

```
public class TranslucentPane extends JPanel {

    private float alpha = 1f;

    public TranslucentPane() {
    }

    public void setAlpha(float value) {
        if (alpha != value) {
            alpha = Math.min(Math.max(0f, value), 1f);
            setOpaque(alpha == 1.0f);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public float getAlpha() {
        return alpha
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(getAlpha()));
        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();

    }

}
```

Next, I would change `panel_Bottom` to actually use it...

```
private TranslucentPane panel_Bottom;

//...

panel_Bottom = new TranslucentPane();
panel_Bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
if(isTransparent){
    panel_Bottom.setAlpha(0.85f);
}
```

[image: Example]

I would also, HIGHLY, recommend that you stop using `null` layouts and learn how to use appropriate layout managers, they will make your life simpler

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: I've added that in but there really doesn't seem to be any change in the buttons behavior. I've also noticed that the pane doesn't become opaque like it should. I've pushed out the new code so that you can see what i'm currently working on.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `setOpaque(alpha == 1.0f);` instance of `setOpaque(alpha != 1.0f);` - Monday morning :P

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be working. The button is still very slowly losing all of it's transparency. What exactly should I be doing with the alpha? I've tried setting the pane to be transparent before setting the color but it still does the same thing. Do I need to change the pane the button uses as well?

Comment: If you're applying a color with a alpha value to the button, then you will have the same problem as described for your `panel_Bottom` and you will need to devise a similar solution.  You CAN'T use alpha based colors with Swing components without first making them transparent (`setOpaque`), but then you need to override their `paintComponent` methods in order to make sure that they are actually still painting their backgrounds

Comment: This was perfect. Tested with synthetica UI. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in GUI-Button line 50 - 
your setter for your background is defect because of a typo.

So if you want to set your background to a new color, nothing is happening.

But I think your problem with transparency is coming from line 199 in GuiSettings - there you are setting a composite value which makes your pixels "darker" after each call. (the reason is the call of the derive method 
with 0.85f as parameter)

Hope I could help you

Comment: That's not where the issue is. If you look in the GUIButton you will see that i am using a standard JPanel. As for the type error, I have already fixed that. It's just not in the newest commit.

Answer (score 0):

> The button is still very slowly losing all of it's transparency.

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the likely problem and solutions.

Basically you need to make sure the background of the parent component is painted first before you paint the transparent background, otherwise you experience the problem you describe.