# how to set opacity on jPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel, transparency, opacity

How to set the opacity of a jPanel in Java NetBeans? As we right click on jPanel and go to properties, there is only one option that is opaque(Related to opacity) which does not set the transparency of panel. How can we set transparency on that particular jPanel?

Comment: You can use this link for better understanding <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517722/java-transparent-jscrollpane>

Comment: Swing only supports full transparent or fully opaque based background colors. In order to be able to support this feature, you will need to make the component transparent (`setOpaque(false)`) you will need override the component's `paintComponent` method and fill it with the transparent color

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105099/jpanel-not-keeping-color-alpha-when-changing-background/31105289#31105289), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216625/how-to-make-a-translucent-jpanel-within-the-region-jpanel/32217554#32217554)

Answer (score -2):

You can use JPanel.setBackground(Color bg); to make the panel transparent or semi transparent

```
panel.setBackground( new Color(r, g, b, a) );
```

Comment: No, you can't. Swing doesn't support alpha based background colors and doing so will generate any number of graphical artifacts