# JScrollPane with background set as setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,122)); glitch

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane` on top of a `JPanel` in which that panel is on a `JTabbedPane` as shown in the image below that is fine when I first enter into the Dashboard Tab and don't scroll but once I scroll down the then the background gives off a complete black background with blurry texts.

[Normal JScrollPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur3Xh.jpg)

[Glitched JScrollPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DIz5.png)

My code for the scroll pane:

```
GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
JScrollPane dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane;
JPanel dashboardSavedTasks  = new JPanel(false);
d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

MainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,122));

dashboardSavedTasks.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
dashboardSavedTasks.setSize(1280,612); 
dashboardSavedTasks.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,612));
//dashboardSavedTasks.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
dashboardSavedTasks.setLocation(0,30);
dashboardSavedTasks.setOpaque(false);
//dashboardSavedTasks.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,122));

//dashboardSavedTasks.add(dashboardSavedTasks,gbcForSavedTasksPanel);

dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane = new JScrollPane(dashboardSavedTasks);

//dashboardSavedTasks.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.magenta));
//dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,100));
//dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920,880));
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setLocation(0,30);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setSize(1280,612);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,612));

//dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setVisible(true);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setViewportView(dashboardSavedTasks);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
//dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,122));
//dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,122));
d.gridx = 0;
d.gridy = 0;
d.weighty = 1;
d.weightx = 1;

MainPanel.add(dashboardSavedTasksScrollPane,d);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPanel not keeping color alpha when changing background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105099/jpanel-not-keeping-color-alpha-when-changing-background)

Comment: In particular, read [MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105289/522444) to the question above.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my problem

Comment: Yay! Be sure to upvote Madprogrammers answer if it helped