# How do you control the transparency of a Swing glass panel?

Tags: java, swing

This is my first time playing with the swing glass  panel.
This class is supposed to show a table covered with glass and the slider at the bottom is supposed to control the amount of transparency of the glass, but it doesn't quite work

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JTableWithGlassPanelExample extends JFrame {

private final JTable table;
private final JPanel glassPanel;
private final JSlider transparencySlider;

public JTableWithGlassPanelExample() {
    super("Transparent Glass Panel on JTable");

    // Create table data and model
    String[] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2"};
    String[][] data = {
            {"Value 1", "Value 2"},
            {"Value 3", "Value 4"},
            {"Value 5", "Value 6"}
    };
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    // Create JTable
    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setRowHeight(30); // Adjust row height as needed

    // Create glass panel with initial transparency
    glassPanel = new JPanel();
    glassPanel.setOpaque(false);

    // Set initial alpha to fully opaque
    int initialAlpha = 122; // 0 for fully transparent, 255 for fully opaque
    glassPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, initialAlpha));

    // Make glass panel consume mouse clicks
    glassPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {}); // Empty listener to consume clicks

    // Implement functionality to move glass panel when dragged
    glassPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // No conversion needed, event already within glass panel coordinates
        }
    });

    // Create transparency slider
    transparencySlider = new JSlider(0, 255, initialAlpha); // Min: fully transparent, Max: fully opaque
    transparencySlider.addChangeListener(e -> {
        int alpha = transparencySlider.getValue();
        glassPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha));
    });

    // Add components to JFrame
    add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setGlassPane(glassPanel); // Set glass panel directly
    add(transparencySlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Set JFrame properties
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 400);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JTableWithGlassPanelExample();
}
```

}

Comment: Swing components don't support alpha based fill colors, you have to fake it instead, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105099/jpanel-not-keeping-color-alpha-when-changing-background/31105289#31105289)

Comment: The glass pane can act as a parent for other components, like popups or tooltips. It’s not meant as a semi-transparent layer nor does it support intercepting input. What you want to achieve, can be done with a [`JLayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayer.html)